# Java program for postfix expression tree

Tags: java, tree, postfix-notation

I have recently been looking into trees in java. I found this code on sanfoundry.com that is pretty awesome for an expression tree. It takes on a prefix then prints out what the prefix expression would look like as an infix and a postfix, and then finally prints the answer out. My question is I am trying to figure out how to simplify it to just take in a postfix and print out the answer for it. So instead of reading in a prefix and doing all that, it would just read in the postfix and print out the answer. Below is the code I found. It is a simple fix to just make it do postfix? Or something much harder?

```
class ExpressionTree
{
/** class TreeNode **/
class TreeNode
{    
    char data;
    TreeNode left, right;

    /** constructor **/
    public TreeNode(char data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }
} 

/** class StackNode **/
class StackNode
{
    TreeNode treeNode;
    StackNode next;

    /** constructor **/
    public StackNode(TreeNode treeNode)
    {
        this.treeNode = treeNode;
        next = null;
    }
}

private static StackNode top;

/** constructor **/
public ExpressionTree()
{
    top = null;
}

/** function to clear tree **/
public void clear()
{
    top = null;
}

/** function to push a node **/
private void push(TreeNode ptr)
{
    if (top == null)
        top = new StackNode(ptr);
    else
    {
        StackNode nptr = new StackNode(ptr);
        nptr.next = top;
        top = nptr;
    }
}

/** function to pop a node **/
private TreeNode pop()
{
    if (top == null)
        throw new RuntimeException("Underflow");
    else
    {
        TreeNode ptr = top.treeNode;
        top = top.next;
        return ptr;
    }
}

/** function to get top node **/
private TreeNode peek()
{
    return top.treeNode;
}

/** function to insert character **/
private void insert(char val)
{
    try
    {
        if (isDigit(val))
        {
            TreeNode nptr = new TreeNode(val);
            push(nptr);
        }
        else if (isOperator(val))
        {
            TreeNode nptr = new TreeNode(val);
            nptr.left = pop();
            nptr.right = pop();
            push(nptr);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid Expression");
    }
}

/** function to check if digit **/
private boolean isDigit(char ch)
{
    return ch >= '0' && ch <= '9';
}

/** function to check if operator **/
private boolean isOperator(char ch)
{
    return ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '*' || ch == '/';
}

/** function to convert character to digit **/
private int toDigit(char ch)
{
    return ch - '0';
}

/** function to build tree from input */
public void buildTree(String eqn)
{
    for (int i = eqn.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        insert(eqn.charAt(i));
}

/** function to evaluate tree */
public double evaluate()
{
    return evaluate(peek());
}

/** function to evaluate tree */
public double evaluate(TreeNode ptr)
{
    if (ptr.left == null && ptr.right == null)
        return toDigit(ptr.data);
    else
    {
        double result = 0.0;
        double left = evaluate(ptr.left);
        double right = evaluate(ptr.right);
        char operator = ptr.data;

        switch (operator)
        {
        case '+' : result = left + right; break;
        case '-' : result = left - right; break;
        case '*' : result = left * right; break;
        case '/' : result = left / right; break;
        default  : result = left + right; break;
        }
        return result;
    }
}

/** function to get postfix expression */
public void postfix()
{
    postOrder(peek());
}

/** post order traversal */
private void postOrder(TreeNode ptr)
{
    if (ptr != null)
    {
        postOrder(ptr.left);            
        postOrder(ptr.right);
        System.out.print(ptr.data);            
    }    
}

/** function to get infix expression */
public void infix()
{
    inOrder(peek());
}

/** in order traversal */
private void inOrder(TreeNode ptr)
{
    if (ptr != null)
    {
        inOrder(ptr.left);
        System.out.print(ptr.data);
        inOrder(ptr.right);            
    }    
}

/** function to get prefix expression */
public void prefix()
{
    preOrder(peek());
}

/** pre order traversal */
private void preOrder(TreeNode ptr)
{
    if (ptr != null)
    {
        System.out.print(ptr.data);
        preOrder(ptr.left);
        preOrder(ptr.right);            
       }    
   }
 }
```

And here is the main method.

```
   /** class ExpressionTreeTest **/
    public class ExpressionTreeTest
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Expression Tree Test");

    /** make object of ExpressionTree **/
    ExpressionTree et = new ExpressionTree();

    System.out.println("\nEnter equation in prefix form");
    et.buildTree(scan.next());

    System.out.print("\nPrefix  : ");
    et.prefix();
    System.out.print("\n\nInfix   : ");
    et.infix();
    System.out.print("\n\nPostfix : ");
    et.postfix();
    System.out.println("\n\nEvaluated Result : "+ et.evaluate());
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Postfix is a linear notation. You don't need a tree at all to evaluate it, only a stack. You're starting from the wrong place.

Comment: Yea i get that. I've actually made a postfix using a stack. I just wanted to know using this could you make it as a postfix tree?

Comment: There is no such as a postfix tree. It's a linear notation. You can have an *expression* tree, which has operators as parents and operands as children, and you can traverse it in prefix, infix, or postfix order: not the same thing. Your question is confused.

Comment: Ok thank you I am starting to understand now. So this works for prefix and is able to calculate it, correct? So are you saying that this is possible for prefix, but not for postfix? Or that I am asking the question in the wrong way? Sorry for all of the questions. I just want to understand this fully.

Comment: I can't even understand your questions, and I don' t know how to make my answer any clearer.